# Run command in new frame

Tags: frames

I'm managing workspaces by creating new frames, but running `C-x 5 C-h` couldn't find anything like "run command in new frame", basically what I'd like to do is to run some REPL or shell in new frame. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just open a new frame and then run the command?  If you do it all the time and want to save a step, you could write a command that does both.

Comment: I like to modify source code and create my own custom custom setup; however, most people seem to prefer chaining functions together or using advice.  To the extent that you want to create your own function to open a shell, the key ingredient to your display issue is the line of the `shell` function (defined within the library `shell.el`) that looks like this:  `(pop-to-buffer-same-window buffer)`.  For example, you might be interested in something like `(swtich-to-buffer-other-frame buffer)`.  There are also those users who prefer to modify the `display-buffer-alist`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply want a programmatic way to run a command in a new frame, just create the frame and run the command:

```
(defun simple-run-command-in-new-frame (command)
  (select-frame (make-frame))
  (funcall #'command))
```

If you want an interactive command that queries for the command being run, similar to `M-x`, then you'll need to take care of details such as handling the prefix argument and querying the user.  The following should work in most circumstances:

```
(defun run-command-in-new-frame (prefixarg command-name)
  (interactive (list current-prefix-arg (read-extended-command)))
  (let ((command (intern-soft command-name)))
    (unless command
      (error "%s is not a valid command name" command-name))
    (select-frame (make-frame))
    (let ((prefix-arg prefixarg))
      (command-execute command))))
```